# Single query for validating user with salt

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have a table with 3 columns: email, pass, salt

When the user logs in, I get the email and pass - but not the salt. How can I validate the user with a single query?

This is what I'm trying to do (but obviously flawed):

```
$query = "SELECT users.salt FROM users WHERE email='$email' AND password='{hash_hmac('sha256', $password, users.salt)}'";
```

Thank you!

Comment: Before you write any more SQL code, please read up on [proper SQL escaping](http://bobby-tables.com/php) to avoid nasty [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/). You need to use SQL placeholders and [bind_param](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php). You **cannot** inline things like `$email` in your queries.

Comment: Thank you for the links, but I know this already - I just simplified the query.

Comment: Don't "simplify" the query by doing this. If you must, put things like `WHERE email=?` instead. What you have here, regardless of your intention, is an example of reckless programming.

Comment: try revising the third parameter of `hash_hmac()`

Comment: Use [`password_hash()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) with `PASSWORD_BCRYPT`.

Comment: Maybe just get the salt and the password thanks to the email, and then check if the password match with the encryption ?

Comment: @tadman so? that's not why i'm here

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't have the users salt from the DB at the point where you are trying to use it to create a hash.

When using a salt-based hash you would typically select the user salt and password from the DB (along with other info you might later need like user ID). And make the hash comparison in your application.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use functions within curly braces: `{hash_mac( ...`

Use this:

```
$query  = "SELECT users.salt FROM users WHERE email='$email' AND password='";
$query .= hash_hmac('sha256', $password, users.salt) . "'";
```

But there is still a problem. `users.salt` will not be available in the PHP context. You will have to get it first:

```
// get salt (pseudo code):
$salt = db_query("SELECT users.salt FROM users WHERE email = '$email'");

// use it in the query
$query  = "SELECT users.salt FROM users WHERE email='$email' AND password='";
$query .= hash_hmac('sha256', $password, $salt) . "'";
```

---

Off topic: As I found this interesting, here comes a basic example howto use a function within curly braces. I'm using the `rand()` function in my example:

```
$rand = 'rand';
echo "{$rand()}";
```

Comment: `users.salt` is failed attempt to reference the "salt" column on the users table.  Your example code won't work for the same reason OP's won't.

Comment: This severely needs proper escaping or `$` values removed and replaced with placeholders. Yikes.

Comment: @FrankFarmer Yes, I see now. Will extend my answer. However, functions aren't allowed in curly braces

Comment: This is a double query, which is what I currently have.

Comment: @steeped You should have told that in the question ;) However, Mike's answer should be what you want

Comment: @hek2mgl Yes - it was in the question title though. Thank you for your help!

Comment: Can be misunderstood in a way like `I have a problem with a single query ...` However, now you are happy and you are welcome ;)

Answer (score 0):

You're mixing PHP and SQL here in a way that can't be done.

This is a really awful way of doing this:

```
SELECT * FROM users
  WHERE email=:email
    AND SHA2(CONCAT(:password, salt), 256)=:hashed
```

Note that this will result in a row scan of all user records in the database and will perform terribly. That's why this approach is never used in production code.

What you're supposed to do is fetch the salt for a particular email, hash the supplied password with it, and then compare the result to the saved hashed value:

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE email=:email
```

If you used a library for this instead of writing your own, you probably wouldn't be having these issues. At least you're not using MD5.

Comment: Maybe someone doesn't like PDO.

Comment: If he had left a comment we would know... :| However, this is correct and especially the `don't use md5()` part should being noted